# Reading Cookies from Express Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm making an app using the Express and [Unblocker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unblocker) modules, along with CookieParser for cookie reading. I have a simple system where an if statement read `req.cookies.visits` and sees if it is 0 or undefined, then redirects to a password screen. However, a problem arises when the Unblocker module is taken into account. Doing

```
app.get('/proxy', function(req, res){
    if(req.cookies.visits==0||req.cookies.visits==undefined){
        res.redirect("/password");
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    }
});
```

doesn't read the cookie for when the request is made (because the route is /proxy/http address). I've tried using express middleware, but doing `req.cookie.visits` results in an undefined error. Unblocker also has a built in middleware functionality, but the page on npm only shows how to do a response and not a request.

Basically, how could I read a cookie with every request and be compatible with this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a full example with middleware :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var Unblocker = require('unblocker');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(new Unblocker({prefix: '/proxy/'}));

function checkVisits(req,res,next){
    let visits;
    try {
        visits = req.cookies.visits;
        if(isNaN(visits)){
            visits = 0;
        }
        console.log("visits:" + visits);
    } catch {
        console.log("no visits");
        visits = 0;
    }finally{
        if(visits === 0){
            res.redirect("/password");
            return;
        }
        res.visits = parseInt(visits)+1;
        res.cookie('visits',res.visits, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
        return next();
    }
}

//add checkVisits(req,res,next) as a middleware
app.get('/index',checkVisits, function (req, res) {
    res.send('index visits:'+res.visits);
  })
//add checkVisits(req,res,next) as a middleware
app.get('/home',checkVisits, function (req, res) {
    res.send('home visits:'+res.visits);
})

app.get('/password', function (req, res) {
    res.send('password page');
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log("App listening on port %s!", port))
```

The checkVisits(req,res,next) middleware will check for visits cookie. If visits cookies is 0 the user will redirected to route /password .

Comment: would this cover all sub-routes (like /proxy/http://example.com)?

Comment: I update my answer with a middleware , to cover all routes after /proxy/*

Comment: This worked, however I had to remove the app.use and just use the unblocker middleware on that specific route, because it was interfering with the cookie middleware. Thank you so much!